# Retornar consulta ordenada por data, não funciona

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM eventos ORDER BY Datainicio DESC
```

Estou a enviar assim para a minha base de dados em mysql é a primeira vez que tento organizar dados por data , alguém me sabe dizer porque que os meus eventos não ficam ordenados ?

Comment: Em que formato tens Datainicio?

Comment: O formato é date Y.m.d

Comment: qual o tipo definido para a coluna "Datainicio" ? e novamente a pergunta, não ficou claro sobre o formato. Está como Y.m.d ou Y-m-d ?

Comment: Tipo queria eu perguntar

Comment: Já disse o tipo de formato  é Y.m.d

Comment: Não, isso é o formato, tipo é se é Text, VarChar...

Comment: Também já tinha dito é do tipo date

Comment: e o que está acontecendo? como está vindo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro resolvido após estudar  , descobri que o phpmyadmin ordena de maneira diferente da real organização dos dados , agora ao aceder através da minha app que estou a desenvolver vi que os dados ja estavam organizados por data.